# why is git ignoring my app.css file

Tags: git

so im using foundation with scss and just wondering why git is ignoring my app.css file when i git add -A. Is that because compass should compile the scss on the fly when you run a compass watch?

Comment: Check your gitignore.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Typically, it's good practice to ignore generated files in git. Foundation probably generated a `.gitignore` with that file in it to encourage this.

Comment: yeah there was a git ignore and it was ignoring /bower_components/*
/.sass-cache/*
*.DS_Store
/stylesheets/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` may contains *.css or something. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by the .gitignore file, check out. It is probably the problem why your css files are ignored.